# Why did John live in the wilderness?

Tags: luke, john-the-baptist

Luke 1:80, "John grew up and became strong in spirit. And he lived in the wilderness until he began his public ministry to Israel."

Luke 3:2, "Annas and Caiaphas were the high priests. At this time a message from God came to John son of Zechariah, who was living in the wilderness."

I wonder why did John end up living in the wilderness and at what age did he move to the wilderness? Did his parents accompany him or was this a solo transition for himself?

Comment: I think these questions can not be answered from known sources. All we can offer is an opinion.

Comment: It can be answered look at how many prophets ended up living in wilderness, Moses, Elijah, Jeremiah so parallel is there obviously